# i want to use ajax in form submission..i am getting error 405--Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

please let me know what kind of changes i need to do in my following code.
here i am inserting data into database,also let me know about suitable JQuery script.
It works fine without the ajax part in the .jsp below. But when I add the jquery ajax part in the jsp, it does not work

```js
here is my controller
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

  @Autowired
  EmpDao dao;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView index() {
    return new ModelAndView("index", "command", new Employee());
  }
  @RequestMapping(value = "/addEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb") Employee e, ModelMap model) {
    dao.saveEmployee(e);
    model.addAttribute("message", "Successfully Inserted....");
    return "index";
  }
}
```

```html
here is my form format

<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Roll:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="roll" id="roll"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="address" id="address"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return doAjaxPost()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div id="info" style="color: green;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</form>
```

Comment: Please post your AJAX code.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 function doAjaxPost() {
var roll = document.getElementById("roll").value;
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
var dataString = 'roll='+ roll + '&name=' + name+ '&address=' + address;  JQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
 url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addEmployee",
 data: dataString,
  
          success: function(data){
                 $("#info").html(data);
             },
             error: function (){}
         });
     return true;
     }
 </script>

Comment: Can you verify in the developer tools' console (network tab) that the URL is generated correctly when you fire your AJAX request?

Comment: correct url has been generated but data is not inserted in database...

Comment: without ajax i could inserted successfully.

Comment: please provide me suitable ajax code and controller format on respective html form format

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't see any problem with your JavaScript code (except that you've written `JQuery.ajax` instead of `jQuery.ajax`.

The error code 405 suggests that the server doesn't support the request method (`POST` in your case) for the specified URL. But as I can see by this line:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

you are already supporting `POST` for `/addEmployee`. And you have already verified that the request URL is being generated correctly by inspecting the browser's developer tools.

So, there may be one of the following cases why your request is being failed:

1. The response of this request is being cached by the browser somehow. Try setting `cache: false` in your AJAX configuration.
2. The AJAX is not being fired entirely, and the form actually gets submitted. To prevent this, you can try the following:

**Change your script**:

```
$(function() {
  $("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var roll = document.getElementById("roll").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var dataString = 'roll=' + roll + '&name=' + name + '&address=' + address;

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addEmployee",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(data) {
        $("#info").html(data);
      },
      error: function() {}
      });
  });
});
```

**Remove onclick handler from HTML**:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

This will dynamically bind the `submit` event handler, and will prevent form's submission to the URL.

Comment: see http://localhost:8080/JdbcTech/index?roll=4&name=hyhjmt&address=yuuuuu  such kind of url has been generated...but not inserted into the database

Comment: and configured jquery is   <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: in my JdbcTech-servlet.xml, i haven't put <mvc:annotation-driven /> tag.....any problem due to this??